# What will be meaning and effect of this integral?

Tags: integration

[image]I was reading an online handout about stability, i have attached snapshot also
What is the meaning of higlighted portion? Is it means that area under the g(t) curve from t=0 to t=infinity is less than infinity??Please guide me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes that's what that means.

Comment: Almost.  It means that $g$ is absolutely integrable.  https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absolutely_integrable_function

Answer (score 0):

It means that the system output must eventually converge to zero, even if it has those oscillations characteristic of a sine cardinal function.
The output of an LTI (Linear Time Invariant) system is obtained with the convolution of the input and the impulse response.
$$y(t) = x(t)*g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty{x(τ)+g(t-τ)dτ}$$
Where $y(t)$ is the output, $x(t)$ the input, and $g(t)$ the impulse response. Now the impulse response is obtained by using a dirac delta function as the input.
$$g(t)=y(t)\space when\space x(t)=(t)$$
The system then responds to the infinite magnitude in an infinitesimal amount of time with the impulse response, and it must converge back to zero in order for the system to be linear and stable. Lets put an example: If  you have a spring hanging from the roof and you pull it down with infinite force in an infinitely small window of time, then the spring will stretch and bounce back to its original place. If the spring doesn't come back to the original position then there must be another force actuating in the spring (it could be a weight attached to the spring) mathematically this force will be translated as a constant to the position which makes it non linear. The system its also time invariant, this means that the spring elasticity cannot be changed nor can be attached a weight after being pulled, it would be ironical for the spring to not come back to the original place, since that would mean that the spring itself is applying a force that prevents it.

The integral in the snapshot is the fancy way to explain this. If the area under $g(t)$ results infinite then it means that the system is injecting energy from another place different of the input, it is not bouncing anymore.